# Select all df cols that have only two specific values, then drop them?

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a huge df (70k cols, all string format) that I'm trying to do some feature reduction. a noticeable amount of the cols have records = "skip" or NaN. .all the other cols have a range of values and records.

I already am swapping the NaN with 'dne' for easier detection.
.fillna("dne", inplace = True)

So How can I identify all cols that have ONLY ('skip' and 'dne') and then drop them?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help:

```
two_values=('skip','dne')

collect={}
for i in df.columns:
    if len(df[i].value_counts())==2:
        collect[i]=df[i]
        df2=pd.DataFrame(data=collect)
    
if len(df2.columns)==1:
    df.drop(columns=df2.columns.to_list(),axis=1,inplace=True)
else:
    for i in df2.columns:
        if (
            two_values[0] in df2[i].value_counts().index and
            two_values[1] in df2[i].value_counts().index
            ):
                df.drop(columns=i,axis=1,inplace=True)
del(df2)
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but it seems to have ground the NB to a halt. Any advice on speeding up?

Comment: We can run just the first "if" statement(len(df[i].value_counts())==2), and make a new dataframe that contains all the columns with just two values, then in that reduced dataframe pass the next 2 "if" statements. (or if there is just one column identified, directly delete that column). I`ll try and edit the code in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

No need to replace 'NaN' with 'dne'.
It is much simpler using [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

# === Create example dataframe === #
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=list('ABCD'), columns=range(20))
df.loc['A',0:9] = 'skip'
df.loc['B',3:11] = 'skip'
df.loc['C',12:19] = 'skip'
df.loc['D',:15] = 'skip'

for _ in range(20):
    df.loc[np.random.choice(list('ABCD')),np.random.choice(range(20))] = 10
# ====== #

# Replace 'skip' with 'NaN'
skipMap = df=='skip'
df.replace('skip',np.nan,inplace=True)

# Drop colums with all NaN
df.dropna(axis=1,how='all',inplace=True)

# If you want revert 'skip' back
df.where(~skipMap,'skip',inplace=True)
```

Comment: ahhh, I see. go the other direction, replace SKIP to NaN, then drop 100% null cols. makes good sense.....but I think I need to preserve "skip" in the rest of the cols as important context info.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, that's what the last line does